# Chart.js not responsive on iOS

Tags: javascript, iphone

I've duplicated the code from this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jyxcodrq/1/ to try and get a chart to compress/be responsive on Safari for iOS.

```
<div class="container" style="display: none;">
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 1px;">
<div class="col s12 l7">
<div style="padding: 10px; padding-left: 0;">
<div style="padding: 10px;">
<canvas id="cloudformation-status-chart" width="200" height="128"></canvas>
</div>
<p style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 1px;">Event duration (in seconds)</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
 new Chart($('#cloudformation-status-chart'), {
            type: 'line',

            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },

                //responsive: false    /* works with this */
            },

            data: {
                labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Stack creation',
                        fill: true,
                        lineTension: 0.3,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                        borderDash: [],
                        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                        pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                        pointBorderWidth: 1,
                        pointHoverRadius: 5,
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                        pointRadius: 3,
                        pointHitRadius: 10,
                        data: [30, 40, 20, 50]
                    }
                ]
            }
        });



        $('div.container').fadeIn();
});
```

Here are screenshots of what it looks like:

- [At desktop size on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAApG.png)
- [Safari Responsive Design Mode's preview of on iPhone SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VCwW.png)
- [An actual screenshot taken on an iPhone SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPd48.png)

As you can see on iOS's Safari the chart doesn't compress down and become responsive as shown on the Responsive Design Mode preview, which is what is desired.

Can anyone help me to get it to be like that?

Comment: did you set a viewport?

Comment: :| Thank you. This fixed it.